# Domain of $x^{\sin x+\cos x}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Why domain of $x^{\sin x+ \cos x}$ is $x\ge 0$ while domain of $x^x$ is $x>0$ 
And if we take the natural logarithim for
 $f(x)= x^{\sin x+ \cos x}$
we get $\ln(f(x))=(\sin x+ \cos x) \ln(x)$ and if $x=0$  we will get  $\ln(0)$ ?

Comment: Please use MathJax to improve the equations.

Comment: It has been edited

Comment: When $x=0$, the first is $0^1$ and the second is $0^0$. The first has a value; the second hasn't.  You can't take the logarithm of either.

Comment: But if we make x^(sinx+ cosx)= x^(sinx) x^(cosx)  And put   x= 0 we will get undefine too??

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x)=x^x$, $\text{dom}(f)=\{x | x\in \mathbb{Z}_{-}\} \cup \{x| x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\}$. But $0 \notin \text{dom}(f)$. In the case of $x^{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}$, you can calculate the value at $x=0$, because $0^x = 0$ $\forall x > 0$.

Comment: But if we make x^(sinx+ cosx)= x^(sinx) x^(cosx) And put x= 0 we will get undefine too??

Comment: @robinisrael The 2 function are not equal, as you can see, because the right hand side is not defined for $x=0$.

Comment: is that because x^(a+b)=x^a x^b just for x>0?

Comment: @robinisrael It's because $0^0$ is undefinied, and one of your factors ($x^{\sin(x)}$) is in thr $0^0$ form.

Answer (score -1):

About the first expression: if you plug $x = 0$ in, you get $0^{0+1} = 0$. In the second you get $0^0$, which is indeterminate. That is why the second expression is not defined for $x=0$.

You cannot compose $\ln$ with $x^{\sin x + \cos x}$ since this expression at $0$ returns $0$. The logarithm is not defined at $0$.

Comment: "Indeterminate" is a property of limit expressions, and there is no limit here. $0^0=1$.

Comment: That is a convention, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero).

Comment: But if we make x^(sinx+ cosx)= x^(sinx) x^(cosx)  And put   x= 0 we will get undefine too??

Comment: Just look at the comment by @Botond above.